# SimpleInjector dictionary as constructor argument

Tags: c#, ioc-container, simple-injector

I'm trying to set up a container to register a class that takes in its constructor a `IDictionary<string, IInterface>` so in my IoC I would like to know how to get a named instance (if that feature is available in SI). An example of what I want to achieve is:

```
container.Register<IOtherInterface>(() => 
    new OtherInterface(new Dictionary<string, IInterface>
    {
        { "a", container.GetInstance<IInterface>("named-a") },
        { "b", container.GetInstance<IInterface>("named-b") },
    });
```

Is there any way to configure this?

Updated:

The implementation of the interface is the same object with different parameters and that's an example I haven't been able to see in the SI documentation https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#resolve-instances-by-key . I'd like to avoid the fact that I have to instantiate a new Interface(..with the relevant parameters...) for each value in the dictionary that's why I thought that naming a registration was something available in SI.

Maybe my approach is wrong and I should try to establish the dependencies in a different way.

Example of usage:

```
public class OtherInterface : IOtherInterface
{
   private readonly IDictionary<string, IInterface> _interfces;

   public OtherInterface(IDictionary<string, IInterface> interfaces)
   {
       _interfaces = interfaces;
   }

   public void DoSomething(MyRequest request)
   {
       if(_interfaces.ContainKey(request.SelectMyInterface))
       {
           _interfaces[request.SelectMyInterface].DoSpecificStuff();
       }
   }
}
```

I could potentially extend the interface IInterface and apply the strategy pattern here having a method like `Applies(string type)` but I have used the dictionary approach in the past with Ninject.

Comment: There is quite extensive documentation about keyed registrations, dictionaries and factories [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#resolve-instances-by-key). If this documentation doesn't answer your question, please update your question with more details (and don't forget to post a comment, to notify any readers that your question has changed).

Comment: Updated with the actual scenario I have. I already read about the keyed registrations but couldn't find anything related to this particular case

Comment: How does `OtherInterface` determine when to use `named-a` or `named-b`? How does it determine the keys `a` and `b`?

Comment: That is passed in its public method call as a property of an object

Comment: Can you post some code that shows this?

Comment: Just did. Like I said I could implement this in a different way and actually I have changed the code so that I don't need the dictionary anymore. Having said that though, I would be interested to know how named instances (same implementation for the same interface but with different bindings) can be resolved using SI if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Keyed registrations are done in Simple Injector by creating `InstanceProducer` instances 'manually' as follows:

```
var a = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<IInterface, A>(container);
var b = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<IInterface, B>(container);
```

Using these instance producers, you can make the dictionary registration as follows:

```
container.Register<Dictionary<string, IInterface>(() => new Dictionary<string, IInterface>
{
    { "a", a.GetInstance() },
    { "b", b.GetInstance() },
});
```

Your `OtherInterface` looks like a dispatcher to me. If it's only job is to route an incoming request, I would say that's okay.

But instead of injecting a dictionary with a complete list of created instances, I would like to propose a bit different design:

```
public class OtherInterface : IOtherInterface
{
   private readonly IDictionary<string, Func<IInterface>> _interfces;

   public OtherInterface(IDictionary<string, Func<IInterface>> interfaces) {
       _interfaces = interfaces;
   }

   public void DoSomething(MyRequest request) =>
       _interfaces[request.SelectMyInterface].Invoke().DoSpecificStuff();
}
```

Here the dictionary contains a `Func<IInterface>`. This way an implementation can be created on the fly, without having to create all implementations on every call.

You can register this as follows:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<IOtherInterface>(new OtherInterface(
    new Dictionary<string, Func<IInterface>>
    {
        { "a", CreateProducer<A>() },
        { "b", CreateProducer<B>() },
    });

private Func<IInterface> CreateProducer<T>() where T : IInterface =>
    Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<IInterface, T>(this.container).GetInstance;
```

Alternatively, you might benefit from a design as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42248281/264697) (and explained in more detail [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)), although it's a bit hard to tell with the limited amount of context given by your question.

Comment: I quite like the Func approach! I would assume though that all the instances would be created only the first time the application bootstraps because OtherInterface would have a LifeStyle.Singleton?

Comment: @CarlosTorrecillas: Whether or not `OtherInterface` is *Singleton* is irrelevant in this case, because the `Func<T>` will forward the call back to the container on each call. This means that the lifestyle of the factory instances is preserved, even though `OtherInterface` is a *Singleton*.